# Filling all the empty cells between two equal cells in same column in excel sheet (with the same value of the equal cells )

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the following excel

[image: the original data]

I am trying the following code

```
> Sub fill_blanks()
 Dim i As Long
 i = 2 '
 Do Until Range("B" & i) = ""
 Range("B" & i).Select
 If ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 <> "" Then
    Range("A" & i).Select
      If ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "" Then
           Range("A" & i - 1).Copy
           Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
           Else
           i = i + 1
      End If
    Else
    i = i + 1
  End If
  Loop
End Sub >
```

What I need to check is if the cell is not empty, then to keep its value, and if it was empty to check the first next not empty cell and the previous non empty cell   in the same column, and if they have the same value, then to fill all the empty cells between with the same value, and if the two cells are not matching, then to return X.

So the result will be as following

[image: What I want]

But using the code , I am getting something different.

This what I get with this code

[image: What I have as a result of my code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are in need of that code you will need to write that code because it does not exist yet. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: You may benefit from reading: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, and write clear description of your issue, including the title.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your replay , I am trying this formula =IF(OR(P79=P81,P79=P82,P79=P83,P79=P84,P79=P85,P79=P86,P79=P87,P79=P88,P79=P89,P79=P90,P79=P91,P79=P92,P79=P93,P79=P94,P79=P95),P79,"x") but I am getting circular reference error , I found some vb cods that copy the previous cell into the empty one  , but this is useless in my case , hope this answered you , and can you tell why I am getting a lot of - on the question ? , thanks again , I am really need this , for my job , otherwise I will fail  . sorry for that all , I am new , this is my 3rd day trying with no success

Comment: @sam22 Actually this is probaply not possible with formulas only and has to be done with VBA. Try to accomplish the following: 1. Loop through all cells in that column until you find an empty one. Remember this cell in a variable and continue the loop until you find a cell that contains data again. Now check the values of above your remebered cell and the actual cell if it is the same fill in the value if it is different fill in x. Continue looping. The [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) will be useful here.

Comment: Give it a try and then come back with the code you tried. Start with researching how to loop through the rows of a column. Go step by step. If you get stuck or errors [edit] your question, add your code and ask a question to that code. People here will then check what is wrong and can help you to fix that specific question.

Comment: Thank again  , I made the edit

Comment: Hi Is it ok now  ?

Comment: Hi Guys can you reopen the question please , I really need to move on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the last used row `LastRow` so we know where to stop.
2. Loop through your rows, when you come accross an epmty cell remember it `FirstEmptyRow`
3. Keep looping until you find data again, the row before is then `LastEpmtyRow`. Now we know the beginning and the end of the empty space.
4. Check if above the epmty space and below the empty space is the same date. If so fill it into the empty space otherwise fill in `x`.

So you end up with something like

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillData()
    Const START_ROW As Long = 2  'define first data row
    Const COL As String = "A"    'define the column

    Dim ws As Worksheet  'define your worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long  'find last used row in column A
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, COL).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim FirstEmptyRow As Long, LastEpmtyRow As Long 'first and last empty row of a empty range

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = START_ROW To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(iRow, COL).Value = vbNullString And FirstEmptyRow = 0 Then
            'found first row of an empty range
            FirstEmptyRow = iRow

        ElseIf ws.Cells(iRow, COL).Value <> vbNullString And FirstEmptyRow <> 0 Then
            'found last row of an empty range
            LastEpmtyRow = iRow - 1

            'check if same date to fill either the date or x
            If ws.Cells(FirstEmptyRow - 1, COL).Value = ws.Cells(LastEpmtyRow + 1, COL).Value Then
                'fill date
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstEmptyRow, COL), ws.Cells(LastEpmtyRow, COL)).Value = ws.Cells(FirstEmptyRow - 1, COL).Value
            Else
                'fill x
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstEmptyRow, COL), ws.Cells(LastEpmtyRow, COL)).Value = "x"
            End If

            'reset variables
            FirstEmptyRow = 0
            LastEpmtyRow = 0
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Illustration of the process.</sup>*